# Prove that $dV(x,y,z)=-\vec{E(x,y,z)} \cdot\vec{ds} \iff V(x,y,z)=-\int_{(x,y,z)}^{\infty} \vec{E(x,y,z)} \cdot \vec{ds}$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, physics

I want to prove that $dV(x,y,z)=-\vec{E(x,y,z)} \cdot\vec{ds} \iff V(x,y,z)=-\int_{(x,y,z)}^{\infty} \vec{E(x,y,z)} \cdot \vec{ds}$.
I keep losing minus sign, I can't find error myself. Every step seems right, although answer is wrong.

1. $dV=-\vec{E} \cdot\vec{ds} \implies V=-\int_{(x,y,z)}^{\infty} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{ds}$ is self evident.
2. $dV(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial V(x,y,z)}{\partial x} dx+\frac{\partial V(x,y,z)}{\partial y} dy+\frac{\partial V(x,y,z)}{\partial z} dz$

$V(x,y,z)=-\int_{(x,y,z)}^{\infty} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{ds} \iff V(x,y,z)=\int_{\infty}^{(x,y,z)} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{ds}$

$V(x,y,z)=\int_{\infty}^{x} {E_x(x,y,z)} dx+\int_{\infty}^{y} {E_y(x,y,z)} dy+ \int_{\infty}^{z} {E_z(x,y,z)} dz$
$dV(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial\int_{\infty}^{x} {E_x(x,y,z)} dx}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial\int_{\infty}^{y} {E_y(x,y,z)} dy}{\partial y}dy+
\frac{\partial\int_{\infty}^{z} {E_z(x,y,z)} dz}{\partial x}dz+$
$dV(x,y,z)={E_x(x,y,z)} dx+{E_y(x,y,z)} dy+  {E_z(x,y,z)} dz$

$dV(x,y,z)=\vec{E(x,y,z)\cdot  \vec{ds}}$

Where is the error?

Comment: what means $\int_{(x,y,z)}^\infty ...$ ?

Comment: It's your very first line which is wrong. It should be $V(x,y,z)= V(x,y,z)-V(\infty)=\int_{\infty}^{(x,y,z)}\,dV=-\int_{\infty}^{(x,y,z)}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}$

Comment: definite Integral that has starting point (x,y,z) and infinite end point.